# SSL does not work on Windows 10 against rutracker.org via PPTP, but works with L2TP

Tags: windows-10, ssl, pptp

I have a Windows 10 laptop with a peculiar problem that no browser can open https://rutracker.org/

It goes like that (in developer tools mode): for a long time browser does not acknowledge that it sends anything to remote (e.g. Chrome reports it is 'stalled'), and then the request is listed as failed with no apparent reason.
I've tried also Firefox and Edge with same results in that they fail to connect and fail to provide any meaningful debug.

I have even installed cURL. The result is the following:

```
curl -k -vvv https://rutracker.org/forum/index.php
* Trying 195.82.146.214...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to rutracker.org (195.82.146.214) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

then it will hang for a long time and then complain of SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. By contrast, on Linux it looks totally different:

```
curl -k -vvv https://rutracker.org/forum/index.php
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 195.82.146.214...
* Connected to rutracker.org (195.82.146.214) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=rutracker.org
*        start date: 2018-07-20 04:13:49 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-10-18 04:13:49 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /forum/index.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: rutracker.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Maybe there is a browser build that will use pure OpenSSL, avoid Windows SSL implementation entirely? Because it seems that it's the problematic thing here. I've checked with Malwarebytes recently which didn't find anything in particular.

*EDIT*: I have observed that it will only happen when I am connected by PPTP VPN. When I have switched to L2TP I can suddently open the website without problems. What is happening here?

Comment: before you edit it sounded like a misconfigured or expired SSL proxy issue. At work I sometimes get that error but for me and easy fix just to clear cache and re-open the page.

Comment: Firefox doesn't use schannel, but it does use winsock2 as does everything else on Windows and the VPN difference suggests a network-level issue. Check your MTUs and segment sizes, or if  you can get a line-level trace like wireshark or netsh look for missing or out-of-sequence frames/segments. Also if you can try curl http: (not S) of a _large_ page (not an error or redirect which are usually small) and see if that is also affected by VPN.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm afraid I just don't have the rigor to do that since I have a working option now. Still would like to know why it might be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Windows' TLS library (and indeed curl on Linux behaves the same way when compiled against OpenSSL/1.1.0i) – it simply uses a newer handshake format which tries to use fewer, larger messages (reducing latency), whereas your curl uses an old library which still has the "SSLv3-compatible" mode.

But that's just one of many things which could trigger the same problem. The real problem is:

1. On the VPN server, the virtual "PPTP clients" network interface has its MTU set to a relatively low value (e.g. 1280 bytes) – to account for the VPN overhead and then some.
2. During the TLS handshake, the Rutracker server sends you an IP packet larger than this MTU.
3. The VPN server cannot forward the packet due to it being larger than the output interface, and returns an ICMP "Too Large" error packet indicating the supported MTU.
4. The Rutracker webserver **ignores** the ICMP message, does not adjust its route cache accordingly, and keeps sending you the same large packet. Start over from step 2.

This ICMP-based MTU negotiation is called "Path MTU Discovery", and the situation where the sender ignores the receiver's advice is known as "PMTU blackhole". Perhaps Rutracker's admins heard somewhere that completely blocking ICMP makes the site somehow "more secure"...

Here's how it looks from an example VPN server's point of view (using a deliberately misconfigured OpenVPN) – note how the large packet is being refused over and over and over:

```
IP 31.220.x.y.48872 > 195.82.146.214.443: Flags [S], seq 2337162999, win 29200, options [mss 1358,sackOK,TS val 674971446 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [S.], seq 2391406816, ack 2337163000, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8], length 0
IP 31.220.x.y.48872 > 195.82.146.214.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, length 0
IP 31.220.x.y.48872 > 195.82.146.214.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:217, ack 1, win 229, length 216
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], ack 217, win 62, length 0
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], seq 1:1359, ack 217, win 62, length 1358
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [P.], seq 1359:3242, ack 217, win 62, length 1883
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], seq 1:1359, ack 217, win 62, length 1358
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], seq 1:1359, ack 217, win 62, length 1358
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], seq 1:1359, ack 217, win 62, length 1358
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
IP 195.82.146.214.443 > 31.220.x.y.48872: Flags [.], seq 1:1359, ack 217, win 62, length 1358
IP 31.220.x.y > 195.82.146.214: ICMP 31.220.x.y unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1280), length 556
```

The L2TP VPN is be unaffected for several possible reasons:

- it could use a default 1500 MTU for the tunnel and transparently fragment the oversized packets;
- it could perform TCP MSS clamping on the connections it sees;
- it could report the reduced MTU to your VPN client software so that your OS already knows upfront to put the right MSS in its TCP connection requests.

As a client, your options are (depending on what the OS supports):

- Don't use PPTP VPNs at all. (Not due to MTU issues – PPTP is no better or worse than other VPN types in that regard – but rather due to security issues that the protocol has. Both the MPPE encryption and the MSCHAP authentication are very weak.)
- Lower the VPN interface's MTU (e.g. to 1400 or 1280) on the client OS. For example, Linux lets you do `ip link set ppp0 mtu <bytes>`. Your system will accordingly advertise a lower TCP MSS value to Rutracker servers.
- Enable TCP MTU probing on the client OS. For example, Linux has `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1`. This works even where ICMP PMTUD does not.
- Configure the VPN client's *or* the VPN server's firewall to perform TCP MSS clamping. (This can be done anywhere along the path.)
- Try to convince the Rutracker admins that they have made a bad decision.